# Error while executing command: mvn test. Reason: exit status 1 - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to install SonarQube using AWS CodeBuild. I am using a Nodejs: 10 as the run time environment. I am getting the below error when I run the below script as the build spec? As I understood, the issue is the NodeJS env does not contain Maven inbuilt. If that is the case, How can I proceed with Maven with in the Node JS Env. Thanks in advance.

> [Container] 2020/07/26 18:16:43 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: mvn test. Reason: exit status 1

Issue occurs when it starts to execute `-mvn test`

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
env:
  secrets-manager:
    LOGIN: SonarCloud:sonartoken
    HOST: SonarCloud:HOST
    Organization: SonarCloud:Organization
    Project: prod/sonar:Project
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - apt-get update
      - apt-get install -y jq
      - wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.tar.gz
      - tar xzf apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.tar.gz
      - ln -s apache-maven-3.5.4 maven
      - wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.3.0.1492-linux.zip
      - unzip ./sonar-scanner-cli-3.3.0.1492-linux.zip
      - export PATH=$PATH:/sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-linux/bin/
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn test     
      - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$LOGIN -Dsonar.host.url=$HOST -Dsonar.projectKey=$Project -Dsonar.organization=$Organization
      - sleep 5
      - curl https://sonarcloud.io/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$Project >result.json
      - cat result.json
      - if [ $(jq -r '.projectStatus.status' result.json) = ERROR ] ; then $CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING -eq 0 ;fi
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Compiling the Node.js code
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - server.js
    - package.json
    - controller/*
```

Comment: You're doing the wrong thing. You cannot use maven/java with nodejs. This will never work like this. Do not try to solve the maven problem, try to work out how to use sonar with nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

> **Maven is available in java : openjdk8.**

You need to add the same to your yml.

**Sample format :**

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8

  build:
    commands:
      - mvn test
```

Comment: That means do I need to specify both NodeJS 10 and OpenJdk 8 in the runtime versions section?

Comment: Yes! You will have to add both of them.

Comment: @Amitkumar I tried as per your suggestion but still not able to achieve the same. Could you please help me with this? This is the error i am getting. YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: Unknown runtime version named 'openjdk8' of java. This build image has the following versions: corretto11, corretto8

Comment: Maven isn't available in openjdk8. Maven is written in, and runs on, a jdk, but the JDK does not come bundled with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Add either `java: corretto11` or `java: openjdk8` or `java: openjdk11`  under  `runtime-versions:` and maven will start executing.

Probably you might need to use your project specific `settings.xml` for maven build, which you can easily provide in a S3 bucket and then refer it under build commands of buildspec.yml

I'm using corretto rather than openjdk in my aws configuration, as aws provide LTS for corretto. Reference - https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/